# Integrating Twitter Bootstrap with Thymeleaf template

Tags: html, spring, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I'm quite new to spring framework, I'm trying to create a template using thymeleaf and Twitter bootstrap to displace a page showing a table of items using JPA. My problem is I'm unable to show the page. Attached here is a screenshot of the error.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" >
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <!--link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Items</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <linkhref="/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="/dashboard/dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Inventory System</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

            <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Welcome <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/items">Items</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li><a href="">New item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Edit Item</a></li>

          </ul>
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">

          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
          <h1 class="page-header">Welcome</h1>

          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Stock Number</th>
              <th>Item Description</th>
              <th>Unit</th>
              <th>ABC</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr th:each="item : ${items}">
              <td th:text="${item.stockNumber}"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<scrip src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Just to make our placeholder images work. Don't actually copy the next line! -->
    <script src="/js/vendor/holder.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGLWk.png)

Comment: <linkhref="/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">, you need a space between `link` and `href`

Comment: also your title is being commented out because you forgot the closing `-->` on the comment above it.